# Renaming dimensions in NCDatasets in julia

Tags: julia

Is it possible to rename dimensions in an NCDataset using julia? Or the only way to deal with this issue is to change the naming in the code?

I tried reading the documentation but there was nothing mentioning how to do it.

Comment: I am using `NCDatasets.jl`  and I want to rename the dimensions

Answer (score 2):

I am not aware of `NetCDF.jl` having this functionality, but you could just use the [NCO / netCDF operators](https://nco.sourceforge.net/) suite for that, it has a [rename](https://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#ncrename) function.

Generally, when handling netCDF files, I think it is a good idea to make use of NCO and [CDO](https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo). Both programs suites are very powerful. I'd advise to mostly stick to reading and writing the files inside of Julia/Python/etc.

Edit: It seems that `NCDatasets.jl` does actually have a function for that, it's just a bit hidden away. You can find [here](https://github.com/Alexander-Barth/NCDatasets.jl/blob/76b19266d790173fe88047036225934f4f66a018/src/dimensions.jl#L105). It's `renameDim`. It doesn't have a doc string, so it won't show up in the documentation. Maybe you could make PR adding one.